# JsonResponse list of dictionaries or nested dictionary

Tags: python, json

I am writing a function which is returning a `JSON` `API` and my output is a list of dictionaries, so in order to pass it to `JsonResponse` I need to pass the `safe = False` value because by default `JsonResponse` requires a dictionary.  I was wondering if it isn't a better choice to re-write my function in order to return a nested dictionary instead.

```
[
 {
   "interface_name": "eno1",
   "ip_address": "10.153.243.19",
   "prefix": 24,
   "mac": "c8:1f:66:b7:f9:0c",
   "state": "UP"
 },
 {
   "interface_name": "eno2",
   "ip_address": "NULL",
   "prefix": 0,
   "mac": "c8:1f:66:b7:f9:0d",
   "state": "DOWN"
 }
]
```

Instead, I guess I can do something like this:

```
{
  "eno1": {
    "ip_address": "10.153.243.19",
    "prefix": 24,
    "mac": "c8:1f:66:b7:f9:0c",
    "state": "UP"
  },
  "eno2": {
    "ip_address": "NULL",
    "prefix": 0,
    "mac": "c8:1f:66:b7:f9:0d",
    "state": "DOWN"
  }
}
```

So what is considered a better practice to return nested dictionaries or list of dictionaries in my case?

Comment: A list of dictionaries is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

If the dictionary keys (`eno1` and `eno2`) in your case do not add more information than list indexes, you should probably use list.